# How to remap Ctrl-j to ENTER on Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac, remapping

How to remap Ctrl-j to ENTER on Mac OS X Yosemite ?

I downloaded & installed Karabiner - but I don't know how can it be done with it?

Maybe it can be done somehow with Alfred?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl-j` (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) is the same as ASCII line feed (which Unix-like systems call *newline*, and is normally mapped by the terminal driver to an ASCII carriage return (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>).  On your main keyboard, *Enter* is normally *carriage return*, while on the keypad, *Enter* is often different (an escape sequence).

While you can check if the terminal driver is set normally (using `stty -a`, and looking for icrnl), it sounds as if your problem is with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).  These pages give some useful advice:

- [HOW TO: Remap keys in OSX using KeyRemap4MacBook (now Karabiner)](https://www.keychatter.com/2014/08/04/how-to-remap-keys-in-osx-using-keyremap4macbook-now-karabiner/)
- [Manual for Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en)

Comment: Sorry for late response & thank you very much for your help.